# How to visualize a map from a netcdf file?

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2, netcdf

I have a netcdf file that I would like to just visualize the soil depth map

```
   [1] "file C:\\Users\\SoilDepth-gswp.nc has 3 dimensions:"
     [1] "x   Size: 360"
     [1] "y   Size: 150"
     [1] "land   Size: 15238"
     [1] "------------------------"
     [1] "file C:\\SoilDepth-gswp.nc has 3 variables:"
     [1] "float nav_lon[x,y]  Longname:Longitude Missval:1e+30"
     [1] "float nav_lat[x,y]  Longname:Latitude Missval:1e+30"
     [1] "float SoilDepth[land]  Longname:Soil depth Missval:1.00000002004088e+20"
```

It seems that I have to connect the latitudes with longitudes as well as the land points to get a map of the soil depth.I am really confused .Can anyone  help me with this kind of data.

Comment: The size of your grid is (360 * 150 = 54e3), while the size of your `land` variable is 15238, which is not a multiple of your gridsize. Do you have an explanation for this?

Comment: Where did you get this data? Or did you create it yourself? The difference might be caused by the presence of NA values, i.e there is no soil depth in the ocean.

Comment: `land` is not a variable but another dimension so it doesn't have to be of size x * y

Comment: @plannapus you are right. I'm not entirely sure what is in the file, but I think this is a file in a specific format made by some researcher, and that you need some of his/her code to be able to interpret the contents of the file correctly. I would try and contact the creator of the file.

Comment: Voting to close as being too localized, this is a problem that is very specfic to this particular file.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
library(ncdf)
# I'm assuming this is the netcdf file you are working with:
download.file("http://dods.ipsl.jussieu.fr/gswp/Fixed/SoilDepth.nc", destfile="SoilDepth.nc")
soil <- open.ncdf("SoilDepth.nc")
#The way to extract a variable is as following:
soil$var[[3]] -> var3 # here, as shown in your question, SoilDepth is the 3rd variable
get.var.ncdf(soil, var3) -> SoilDepth

dim(SoilDepth)
[1] 15238
```

As was said in the summary for your netcdf file, the variable `SoilDepth` depends on dimension `land` only and not on `x` and `y` so I'm not sure where does that leave you when it comes to plotting this dataset.

**Edit**

It turns out there is a key that links `x`, `y` and `land`:

```
download.file("http://dods.ipsl.jussieu.fr/gswp/Fixed/landmask_gswp.nc", destfile="landmask.nc")
landmask <- open.ncdf("landmask.nc")
landmask$var[[3]] -> varland
get.var.ncdf(landmask, varland) -> land
sum(land==1)
[1] 15238
```

So in order to plot:

```
# The values where stored in an expected order, hence the transpose
land = t(land)
land[land==1] <- SoilDepth
land[land==0] <- NA
land = t(land)
image(land)
```

[image]

Comment: Just calling plot on the result of `get.var.ncdf(nc, "SoilDepth")` also does not yield a nice timeseries. Strange file...

Comment: There is probably an implicit relationship between dimension `land` and dimensions `x` and `y` but I cant seem to find it...

Comment: I also have a hard time finding a relationship. The OP needs to ask the creator of the data...

Comment: Ok maybe this file here: http://dods.ipsl.jussieu.fr/gswp/Fixed/landmask_gswp.nc is the key.

Comment: The data was read incorrectly, the order in `SoilDepth` was wrong. First transposing, than assigning `SoilDepth`, and transposing back solved the problem.

Comment: If you have an new problem, please post a new question.

Comment: @plannapus the OP posted that the result was wrong as a comment to the answer of AllenR.

Comment: I added this codes to extract the file and write to a binary file using"""""" :to write =file(paste("C:\\Users\\aalyaari\\Desktop\\landmask_gswp.bin",sep=""),"wb")""""""" writeBin(as.double(land),to.write,size=4)""""" when visualizing, the map was flipped upside down!!! – any suggestion why. how to past a map along with the question here?I couldn't

Comment: @WafaAlyaari When you're entering a question or an answer there is a little icon (representing a polaroid or something) you need to click in order to enter an image (you need at least 10 reputation points to be allowed to do so, which is your case). Considering the new issue you're having seems to be very different from your first issue, you should post it as a new question instead of editing your original question.

Answer (score 13):

I prefer to use the `ggplot2` package for visualization. Using the excellent solution of @plannapus:

```
require(reshape)
require(ggplot2); theme_set(theme_bw())
land_df = melt(land)
ggplot(aes(x = X1, y = X2, fill = value), data = land_df) + 
  geom_raster() + coord_equal() + 
  scale_fill_continuous(na.value = "transparent")
```

[image]

---

If you want to change the title of an axis, do *not* change the variable name in `aes`. These values refer to columns in the data, and changing them leads to the error you get, there is no axis named `X` in `land_df`. If you want to change the name placed on the axis:

```
ggplot(aes(x = X1, y = X2, fill = value), data = land_df) + 
  geom_raster() + coord_equal() + 
  scale_fill_continuous(na.value = "transparent") + 
  scale_x_continuous("X")
```

Comment: If they bother you, you should be able to remove them by doing:
+theme(axis.title=element_blank())

Answer (score 5):

Do you want to visualize it with R ?

If it is not a problem to visualize with another software, you can use **ncBrowse**, available [here](http://www.epic.noaa.gov/java/ncBrowse/), or **Panoply**, a more complex one, provided by NASA, which you can donwload [here](http://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/panoply/).

If you want to work with R, you can use `ncdf` package. You will be able to extract your data thanks to the `get.var.ncdf`function. You can plot it thanks to the `sp` package and `spplot`function or use the `rgl`package (or else `scatterplot`).

Comment: I added some code to fix this problem to the answer of @plannapus

Answer (score 4):

For quickly looking at files you can use `ncview`. The maps are not particularly pretty, but very functional for getting an idea of what a given file looks like. Also this works easily on remote servers.

See here: [http://meteora.ucsd.edu/~pierce/ncview_home_page.html](http://meteora.ucsd.edu/%7Epierce/ncview_home_page.html)