# How to map numbers to colours?

Tags: r, plot, raster

I am trying to view this file(unsigned character, pixel =1440 and lines=720) as a map. I tried the piece of code given bellow. First, I downloaded  may problem is that this code is using a continuous colour scheme, even though I have discrete data (which  is a classification scheme). How can I map numbers to colours ? Please 
example of  a wanted scale is shown below:

```
conne <- file("C:\\landcover.bin", "rb")
dfr<- readBin(conne, integer(), size=1,  n=720*1440, signed=F)

y<-matrix((data=dfr), ncol=1440, nrow=720)
image(y)
```

Comment: Generally, you can scale your values into [0,1] then multiply those by the number of colours -1 (with +1 to avoid the 0 index), and use that to index into the colours. For images, it's a bit easier since you can use the breaks and cols arguments for image().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `raster` package provides a method to use categorical
data. Read the help page of `ratify` for details.

First let's create a `RasterLayer` with your data:

```
library(raster)

dfr <- readBin('biome1440s.bin', integer(), size=1,  n=720*1440, signed=F)
r <- raster(nrow=720, ncol=1440)
r[] <- dfr
```

Now we define this `RasterLayer` as a factor with `ratify`. You
should change its levels using your information instead of `LETTERS`:

```
r <- ratify(r)
rat <- levels(r)[[1]]
rat$soil <- LETTERS[1:15]
levels(r) <- rat
```

And finally, this categorical `RasterLayer` can be displayed with
the `levelplot` method of the `rasterVis` [package](http://rastervis.r-forge.r-project.org/).

```
library(rasterVis) 
myPal <- c('lightblue', terrain.colors(14))
## using par.settings
levelplot(r, par.settings=rasterTheme(region=myPal))
## or with col.regions
levelplot(r, col.regions=myPal)
```

[image: world land uses]

Edited: `levelplot` uses `lattice` graphics, while `plot` uses
`base` graphics. They cannot be used together (unless you use the
`gridBase` package). However, you can easily overlay additional
information using the `+.trellis` and `layer` functions from the
`latticeExtra` package. Since `wrld_simpl` is a
`SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` you can use the `sp.polygons` function
from the `sp` package to plot it.

```
library(maptools) ## needed for wrld_simpl
data(wrld_simpl) ## a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
levelplot(r, col.regions=myPal) +
    layer(sp.polygons(wrld_simpl, lwd=0.5))
```

[image: wrld_simpl]

Comment: @ZadSim Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean with "k".

Comment: @ZadSim I have added an additional chunk code to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, no code can use "continuous" color schemes, because all data are digital and quantized.
Now,  there are lots of built-in color patterns in `R` .  See `?image` for a discussion of some of the common palettes used for maps and the like.  If your map data has discrete ranges of numerical values for the various soil types, a little scaling math will let you apply different colors to each category.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use the excellent ggplot2 package. This has the `geom_raster` geometry which should work just fine with your data. Note that `ggplot2` requires its data to be in a different format than a matrix, you can use `melt` from the `reshape2` package to perform this conversion. See also my answer to [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12285120/how-to-visualize-a-map-from-a-netcdf-file/12295601#12295601), which has a lot of similarities with you own.

Comment: In your question y is not a raster layer.